# SQL migration - move data to another table and get the primary key

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, migration

### Problem

Suppose a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
  parent_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  col1 REAL,
  col2 REAL
);
```

Then the requirements of the system change and `parent` need to have the information `col1` and `col2` at two different points in time. One possible design would be the creation of a separate table for `col1` and `col2`:

```
CREATE TABLE child (
  child_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  col1 REAL,
  col2 REAL
);

CREATE TABLE parent (
  parent_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  current_child INTEGER,
  previous_child INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (current_child) REFERENCES child (child_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (previous_child) REFERENCES child (child_id)
);
```

### Questions

1. Is there a way to create a migration SQL script to move the data from the original `parent` table to `child` and set the correct foreign key at `current_child`?

   - `previous_child` could stay empty initially, this is not a problem.
   - I'm not concerned yet about removing the columns `col1` and `col2` from `parent`.
   - I'm avoiding to use auxiliary scripts in other languages (like in Python) to make the migration process simpler.
2. Is there a better design alternative?

   - I could have simply added two new columns `previous_col1`  and `previous_col2`, but I have many more columns in the real scenario.

PS.: It is probably relevant to know that I'm using SQLite.

### Update

@Felix.leg asked an excellent question and I noticed that I was stuck with the idea of always using automatically generated PK values for both tables. The truth is that `child_id` could be defined from `parent_id`:

- `current_child = 2 * parent_id - 1`
- `previous_child = 2 * parent_id`

With this approach, I believe it would be possible to write a single SQL migration script to create the new table, move the data, and set the right foreign key values.

Comment: what 'col1' and 'col2' represents? How a value of 'child_id' in table 'child' should be chosen?

Comment: Excellent question, @Felix.leg! Your question answered mine. The meaning of "col1" and "col2" might not be relevant, but "child_id" could be defined in relation to "parent_id" in a migration script. This would solve my problem. I was stuck with the idea of always generating automatic PK values, which were hard to set back in "parent".